# Pandas compare two columns and copy value of another column if there is a match only for first unique value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dataframes of which I want to compare two columns. If the value of the first dataframe appears anywhere in the column of the second dataframe, I want to copy the value next to the matching value and copy this to a new column in the first dataframe.

The dataframes look like this:

DF1

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║       Email       ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║ Johndoe@gmail.com ║
║ janedoe@gmail.com ║
║ foo@gmail.com     ║
║ foobar@gmail.com  ║
║ bar@gmail.com     ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```

DF2

```
╔════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║       Email        ║    Phone    ║
╠════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Johndoe@gmail.com  ║ 111-111-111 ║
║ Johndoe@gmail.com  ║ 111-111-111 ║
║ Johndoe@gmail.com  ║ 111-111-111 ║
║ Jakedoe@gmail.com  ║ 123-123-123 ║
║ jamesdoe@gmail.com ║ 321-321-321 ║
║ janedoe@gmail.com  ║ 222-222-222 ║
║ janedoe@gmail.com  ║ 222-222-222 ║
║ foo@gmail.com      ║ 333-333-333 ║
║ foobar@gmail.com   ║ 444-444-444 ║
║ foobar@gmail.com   ║ 444-444-444 ║
║ bar@gmail.com      ║ 555-555-555 ║
╚════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

The output should look like this:

```
╔═══════════════════╦═════════════╗
║       email       ║    phone    ║
╠═══════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Johndoe@gmail.com ║ 111-111-111 ║
║ janedoe@gmail.com ║ 222-222-222 ║
║ foo@gmail.com     ║ 333-333-333 ║
║ foobar@gmail.com  ║ 444-444-444 ║
║ bar@gmail.com     ║ 555-555-555 ║
╚═══════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I've tried looping over the column in DF1 and comparing every value to the corresponding column in DF2 but it also returns the duplicates.

What would be a good way to accomplish this with Pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then `.drop_duplicates()`

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on='Email', how='left').drop_duplicates()
```